# Returning current URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, return-value

I am trying to implement canonical and hreflang tags in WordPress, but I cannot retrieve the current URL of the visited page.

I tried :

```
 <?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

But it returns `https://www.example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com/current-page1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone else needs this. Below code should get the exact URL including parameters.

```php
home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

You can echo or return it depending on your use case.
e.g.

```php
echo home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

or

```php
return home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: it is not working for wp installed in subfolder. it doubles subfolder

Comment: @SergeyKorzhov is right. what is the solution if Wp is installed in a subfolder?

Answer (score 7):

The [`site_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/) function returns the actual website root URL. Depending on where you are calling your URL you could try [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) but a more surefire way would be to use the [`$wp->request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/request/) method. Like this:

```
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request )
```

The main problem with this function is that the URL parameters are left out, so if your link is something like: `http://example.com/test/?myparam=1` it will only return `http://example.com/test/`

Comment: Thanks for the details... I don't have parameters except "?s=" for the onsite searches (so yeah, it's a parameter !)

Comment: That should be fine, assuming that your function is running during the object loop, as it will return the URL of that object without parameters, and not the search page's URL :) - will test it in a bit to make sure though as I am running off of memory here (which I'll admit can sometimes let me down) :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents. The approaches described are using `$_SERVER` global without verifying the integrity of each query variables.

Unregistered variable/value couples are being displayed even tho they're not part of the WordPress public query environment `WP_Query` class (recognized by `WP_Query`).

I would suggest comparing each query variables against the public query variables scope before returning the current permalink.

```
<?php

/**
 * Safely retrieve the current permalink.
 * Filters-out unregistered query variables through WordPress core get_query_var() function.
 * Make it safe to use in database queries, redirects and HTTP requests through WordPress core esc_url_raw() function.
 *
 * @param String $args['relative'] (true|false), Relative path if true. Default to false. 
 *
 * @return String Relative or absolute path to the current permalink.
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809779/3645650
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpso_50761584' ) ) {

    function wpso_50761584( $args = array() ) {

        $args = empty( $args ) ? array(
            'relative' => false,
        ) : $args;

        global $wp;

        parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $variables );

        $buffer = array();

        foreach ( $variables as $variable => $value ) {

            if ( get_query_var( $variable ) )

                array_push( $buffer, array( $variable => $value ) );
            
        };

        $buffer = array_reduce( $buffer, 'array_merge', array() );

        $permalink = $args['relative'] ? wp_make_link_relative( esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( $buffer, home_url( $wp->request ) ) ) ) : esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( $buffer, home_url( $wp->request ) ) );

        return $permalink;

    };

};
```

As an example, you could echo-it-out on the front end:

```
<?php

echo wpso_50761584( 
    array(
        'relative' => true
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If permalinks set to the plain:

```php
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: This is useful for plain permalinks, but worth pointing out that it doesn't add `http://` or `https://`, which generally is not a problem, might be worth editing your answer and mentioning that, just in case :)

Comment: Tried this, but still return root url.

Comment: Still the same... soes it matter that i'm not using basic WP theme ? Maybe there is a different function...